# How to Bind Datagrid using MVVM Pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Goal:**

I am currently aiming to connect the Datagrid and the ViewModel. The ViewModel currently has code that gets data from MySQL.

Not sure where to go from here or if I am doing it correctly...

**Technical_Fsqm.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="FSQM"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="FSQMData"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding data}" Margin="0,106,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

**Technical_Fsqm.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Technical_Fsqm : UserControl
{
    public Technical_Fsqm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Technical_FsqmVM();
    }
}
```

**Technical_FsqmVM.cs**

```
using Dapper;

public class Technical_FsqmVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public List<FsqmModel> data()
    {
        string query = "select * from table;";

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var output = conn.Query<FsqmModel>(query).ToList();

            return output;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class FsqmModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWw7qKDWKkU  may help

Comment: @KamranMammadov Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is is not possible to create binding with method, only with property:

```
public partial class Technical_Fsqm : UserControl
{
    public Technical_Fsqm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new Technical_FsqmVM();
        vm.LoadData();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

vm

```
public List<FsqmModel> data { get; private set; }

public void LoadData();
{
    string query = "select * from table;";

    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        data = conn.Query<FsqmModel>(query).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Meaning the `ItemSource` is unnecessary?

Comment: By the way, you can create binding with a method. See binding via `ObjectDataProvider`.

Comment: @Rekshino, if smth can be done, doesn't mean it should be done. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8. and ObjectDataProvider isn't binding.